# Django Python urlencode same key with multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls

As the title suggest I am trying to urlencode using Ordered Dict in python

```py
def url_replace(request, field, value, direction=""):
    dict_ = request.GET.copy()
    if field == "order_by" and field in dict_.keys():
        if dict_[field].startswith("-") and dict_[field].lstrip("-") == value:
            dict_[field] = value
        elif dict_[field].lstrip("-") == value:
            dict_[field] = "-" + value
        else:
            dict_[field] = direction + value
    else:
        dict_[field] = direction + str(value)

    print("UNORDERED___________________")
    print(dict_)
    print(super(MultiValueDict, dict_).items())
    print("ORDERED_____________")
    print(OrderedDict(super(MultiValueDict, dict_).items()))
    print(OrderedDict(dict_.items()))
    return urlencode(OrderedDict(dict_.items()))
```

The output for the above code

```
UNORDERED___________________
<QueryDict: {'assigned_to_id': ['1', '2'], 'client_id': ['2', '1'], 'page': ['2']}>
dict_items([('assigned_to_id', ['1', '2']), ('client_id', ['2', '1']), ('page', ['2'])])
OrderedDict([('assigned_to_id', '2'), ('client_id', '1'), ('page', '2')])
ORDERED_____________
OrderedDict([('assigned_to_id', ['1', '2']), ('client_id', ['2', '1']), ('page', ['2'])])
OrderedDict([('assigned_to_id', '2'), ('client_id', '1'), ('page', '2')])
```

As you can see the assigned_to_id has only `2` in the end .

What I am expecting is a ordered dict with

```
OrderedDict([('assigned_to_id', '2'),('assigned_to_id', '1'), ('client_id', '1'), ('client_id', '2'),('page', '2')])
```

Maybe there might be a better approach for this, I am a bit new to python

My final aim is to return a dict with multiple keys or anything that can be used in urlencode

Comment: Which package does `urlencode` come from, or an example of what you expect the `url_replace` function to return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.parse.urlencode)

> When a sequence of two-element tuples is used as the query argument, the first element of each tuple is a key and the second is a value. The value element in itself can be a sequence and in that case, if the optional parameter `doseq` evaluates to True, individual key=value pairs separated by '&' are generated for each element of the value sequence for the key. The order of parameters in the encoded string will match the order of parameter tuples in the sequence.

Here is a simple example:

```py
from urllib import parse

print(parse.urlencode({"a": [1, 2], "b": 1}, doseq=True))
# "a=1&a=2&b=1"
```